Did Aisha (RA) hit her face when Prophet Muhammad (saw) passed away
Are the Hadiths that say that Aisha (RA), along with the other woman, started hitting her face in grief when Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) passed away authentic?

مات رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بين سحري، ونحري وفي دولتي، لم أظلم فيه أحدا، فمن سفهي وحداثة سني أن رسول الله قبض وهو في حجري، ثم وضعت رأسه على وسادة، وقمت ألتدم مع النساء، وأضرب وجهي
They have recounted that ‘A’ishah said,
The Messenger of Allah (may Allah bless him and give him peace) passed away leaning against my chest. I did not wrong anyone regarding him. It was from my weakness and the youth of my age that the Messenger of Allah was taken whilst in my lap, then I placed his head on a pillow and stood hitting myself along with the women and hitting my face.
— Musnad Ahmad - (translation from seekersguidance.org)

and if so, how should we interpret these narrations, given that Islam prohibits such displays of mourning? I have also heard that the prohibition applies to making such actions a habitual or deliberate practice, while instinctive reactions due to overwhelming grief may not be considered sinful. Is this true?

Why don't you quote the ahadith which you are asking about?

Please Quote the Arabic Source of Hadith!

Al-Arnaa’oot when commenting on the hadith in Musnad Ahmad has stated that the report has a hassan chain and that the addition of hitting the face is an oddity that is absent from other versions of the report.
If it is authentic then it has been explained as follows: In this report Aisha reproaches herself and shows regret for her action, giving the excuse that she was young and inconsiderate. So the report is not useful as evidence of what is permissible.
Ref: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/62097 and https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/354364/
